# How to convert textarea text into canvas image by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, word-wrap, textinput

I am trying to convert my textarea text into canvas image. that text needs to be displayed in canvas as an image. But sometimes my text is perfectly showing in canvas but the sentences are breaking into words and switching to the next lines. Line breaks are occuring due to which sentences are in improper format. I want to display the text in my textarea and in my canvas in a wrap format. In my below code i am not getting any output . Please advise with best.

```
   <body>
   <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>

   <form id="myForm">
    Text: <input id="myText" placeholder="your text"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>

  <script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var imageObj = new Image();

  imageObj.onload = function()
  {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
  }  

   imageObj.src = "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-background-in-geometric-style_1013- 
    17.jpg"; 

    var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
    myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e)
     {
    var text = document.getElementById('myText').value;

      if(text.length == 0)
      {
         alert("you forgot to put something");
      }
      else
      {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");  
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");  
        var maxWidth = 400;  
        var lineHeight = 25;  
        var x = (canvas.width - maxWidth) / 2;  
        var y = 60;  
        var text = document.getElementById("myText").value; 
        context.font = "16pt Calibri";  
        context.fillStyle = "#333"; 
        context.fillText(text, 50, 50); 
        wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight);  
        e.preventDefault();}
        });
       </script>
       </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) for this purpose.